# How to select text in GtkEntry

Tags: c, gtk, gtkentry

i have dialog window with GtkEntry. I want to select all text in entry right after dialog window becomes visible to user. I tried this, but its not working, i see no selection:

```
static void OnEntryShow(GtkWidget *entry, gpointer user_data)
{
     gtk_editable_select_region(GTK_EDITABLE(entry), 0, -1);
}
...
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(myEntry), "text");
g_signal_connect(myEntry, "show", G_CALLBACK(OnEntryShow), NULL);
if (gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG(myDialog)) == GTK_RESPONSE_OK)
...
```

How can i select text in GtkEntry after GtkDialog becomes visible?

Comment: Your method should work. This may sound a little obvious but does the entry have text set? How have you set the text?

Comment: Is the signal handler actually getting called? Maybe the widget is already shown by the time you connect the signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want the GtkEntry to grab focus?

Try this:

```
gtk_widget_grab_focus (entry);
```

where `entry` is in this case the pointer to your GtkEntry widget.

The documentation of the function can be found [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-grab-focus).

Answer (score 4):

You should use the function documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEditable.html#gtk-editable-select-region).

`text_entry.select_region(0,2)` will select the first two characters, while `(0, -1)` will select the entire text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've used for gtkmm using the `get_iter_at_offset` and `select_range` functions.

```
Gtk::TextIter match_start = m_textBuffer->get_iter_at_offset(0);
Gtk::TextIter match_end = m_textBuffer->get_iter_at_offset(-1); // -1 to select all
m_textBuffer->select_range(match_start,match_end);
```